# Write a recursive loop in DotLiquid

Tags: c#, templates, liquid, dotliquid

I have this loop in [DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/):

```
{% for page in Page -%}
    {{ page.Title }}
    <ul>
       {% for subpage in page.Pages -%}
           <li>{{ subpage.Title }}</li>
           <!-- subpage.Pages has more pages and so on... -->
       {% endfor -%}
    </ul>
{% endfor -%}
```

Every `subpage` object has a `Pages` property with other subpages in a list (like the first `Page` object.

How to I write a recursive iteration over these subpages to create the complete tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your code into a separate file, and use the `include` tag.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5946708/208817) related question includes some example template code - it's for the Ruby version of Liquid, but it should be directly portable.

Depending on what you need to do, you can either set `Template.FileSystem` to the built-in `LocalFileSystem` to resolve includes, or create your own. See the [source code for `LocalFileSystem`](https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid/blob/master/src/DotLiquid/FileSystems/LocalFileSystem.cs) for an example implementation of `IFileSystem`.

Comment: Oh an answer from the author himself, thanks! May I say that I really like DotLiquid? :) I will implement the FileSystem, wasn't aware of that, and see if I can make it.

Comment: Actually after implementing the LocalFileSystem to load the template in DotLiquid is `{% include MyTemplate %}` instead of `{{ include 'menu_item' with menu_items }}` as listed in the related question. I know, its for the Ruby version, I just wanted to mention it here for other people ;)

Comment: @Tim Jones Is it possible to pass an object to included template from disk file?

Comment: @PitDigger Yes, it is - actually Marc's comment is correct. You can do something like `{{ include 'product' with products[0] }}, and that will pass the `products[0]` object to the `product` template. The variable name you use to access that object inside the included template is the name of the template itself - i.e. `product` in this example.